# Function to round number to nearest "smooth" number

Tags: javascript

Definition of smooth number from my point of view:
10, 50, 100, 200, 300, 400, ... 1000, 2000, 3000 ... 10000, etc.

I have dynamically coming data with some numbers (for example, single array of numbers).

I don't know, how huge number can be, and I want to round it to nearest "smooth" number.

For example:

I wan't to round `54` to `50` or, to `100`. (Would be nice to have 3 options: rounding up, rounding down, and rounding to nearest, e.g. 54 to 50, 94 to 100 )

While huge number like `209282938` should be rounded to `200000000` or to `300000000`

How function should look like?

Comment: Why not 54 to 50?

Comment: You need to explain your logic better.

Comment: Why not 54 to 60?

Comment: It sounds like you want to always round up and always have one significant digit.  Is that correct?

Comment: @Amy Can be 60, not so important.

Comment: @BenM What exactly you didn't understand?

Comment: @Klimenkomud it *is* important, otherwise we can't understand what you actually want to do. Be aware that "prettify" means nothing in this context, that's part of why we're confused.

Comment: Why is `54` rounded to `100` (or `60` *not important*), but `2051075640` is rounded to `3000000000` and not `2051075650`, for example.

Comment: @KurtSchwanda I always wan't to round to nearest smooth number.

Comment: Then explain how 60 would not be “smooth”.

Comment: What is "smooth"?

Comment: @Klimenkomud what people were getting at earlier is that "prettify" and "smooth" aren't precisely defined.  People want to help, but don't know exactly what behavior you desire.

Comment: @misorude As I said, would be.

Comment: Ok, but you still have to make up your mind, whether you want 60 or 100 now for the input value 54 …

Comment: @misorude or 50, for that matter! :)

Comment: @misorude Can even be 50. Take a look at 1 answear, that guy understand my idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**OPTION 1**

You could use `.toPrecision()`

[It is explained in more detail here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toPrecision) but basically you can specify the number of significant figures, e.g.

```
function precise(x) {
  return Number.parseFloat(x).toPrecision(1);
}

console.log(precise(54));
// output: "50"

console.log(precise(2051075640));
// output: "2000000000 "

console.log(precise('99.999'));
// output: "100"
```

---

**OPTION 2**

If you wanted to always round up or always round down, you could use  `.ceil()` and/or `.floor()`

Note: these round to the nearest integer but you could process the input to utilize them:

1. Work out how many digits the input has
2. Divide it by the appropriate multiple of 10
3. Use `.ceil()` or `.floor()`
4. Multiply by the same multiple of 10 as before

Comment: Perfect! I think playing a bit with that will give the most desirable, thanks a lot

Comment: The question specifies that 54 should go to 100.  This says it goes to 50.  Is it perfect?  It doesn't appear to fulfill the stated requirements.

Comment: @Amy I assumed this was unintentional, the question has since been amended.

Comment: @Amy I update my question a bit, to make it more clear. The idea is not to come to some specific solution, but, as question header says, prettify the number. Each one understand with prettifying different things, but in general, as I think, it can be understood as "nearest flat/smooth number". I hope you catch my idea.